# How to programmatically order the currently focused window to ask for clipboard contents in X11?

Tags: linux, clipboard, x11

I'm writing a personal project to write arbitrary unicode strings into the currently focused window. The way I'm doing it is to copy the string into the clipboard and paste it by simulating the "C-V" keypress programmatically. This works well enough on anything that maps "C-V" to pasting, but programs like emacs or the terminal don't do this.

How can I send any program the 'paste' command without using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Maybe `xdotool` can be of help.

Comment: To manipulate the clipboard from the command-line or in scripts there are utilities such as `xclip`, `xsel` and probably others.